# how add an arrow pointing to the y-axis on highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I show an arrow pointing to the middle of y-axis on highcharts as below image: [image]

and this is my y-axis:

```
yAxis: [{
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Your starting point',
                    style:{
                        font: '6px arial'
                    }
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 1000
            }]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by

1) using an image, or an icon font, in your axis title

2) using the Highcharts renderer function to draw the arrow

reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer